# Prove using Lagrange's Mean Value Theorem, $\frac{x^2}{2} > x - \ln(1 + x) > \frac{x^2}{2(1 + x)}$ for all $x>1$

Tags: real-analysis, mean-value-theorem

By taking $f(x) = \ln(1 + x)$ and using the inequality $\frac{1}{1 + x} < \frac{1}{1 + c} < 1$ for $c \in (0, x)$, applying LMVT gives $\frac{x}{1 + x} < \ln(1 + x) < x$.

By taking $f(x) = x - \ln(1 + x)$ and using the inequality $1 - \frac{1}{1 + x} > 1 - \frac{1}{1 + c} > 0$ for $c \in (0, x)$, applying LMVT gives $\frac{x^2}{1 + x} > x - \ln(1 + x) > 0$.

But I am unable to find a function to prove $\frac{x^2}{2} > x - \ln(1 + x) > \frac{x^2}{2(1 + x)}$.

I know it can easily be solved using Taylor's theorem, but I want to solve it using LMVT.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{array}\\
f(x)
&=x - \ln(1 + x)\\
&=x - \int_0^x \dfrac{dt}{1+t}\\
&=\int_0^x (1-\dfrac1{1+t})dt\\
&=\int_0^x \dfrac{1+t-1}{1+t}dt\\
&=\int_0^x \dfrac{t}{1+t}dt\\
&\ge\int_0^x \dfrac{t}{1+x}dt
\qquad \text{(since }1+t \le 1+x)\\
&=\dfrac1{1+x}\int_0^x tdt\\
&=\dfrac{x^2}{2(1+x)}\\
f(x)
&=\int_0^x \dfrac{t}{1+t}dt\\
&\le\int_0^x tdt
\qquad \text{(since } 1+t \ge 1)\\
&=\dfrac{x^2}{2}\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: thank you for answering, but this method doesn't use the LMVT.